# Performance issue when using LIKE in joins

Tags: mysql, performance, join

We have a ecommerce website. We give creditvouchers to customer. He can use this in 1,2...n orders which he places further. 
Say We issued creditvoucher called 'abcd'. When he splits and uses the voucher and uses in order, it will come in adjustment like abcd-1 etc. So i am trying to make a report which lists all creditvouchers issued and orders placed with these vouchers. I wrote the below query. It works fine, but it takes lot of time to load. Any thing i can do for performance?

```
SELECT *
FROM (creditvouchers)
LEFT JOIN adjustment ON `adjustment`.`code` 
                    LIKE IF((creditvouchers.creditvoucher = ''),
                        creditvouchers.creditvoucher,
                        CONCAT(creditvouchers.creditvoucher,'','%'))
```

Here are the tables

```
creditvouchers -> id PK, creditvoucher varchar(50)
adjustment     -> id PK, code varchar(50)
```

Comment: Keep a column with the *real* `creditvoucher` (`abcd`) rather than join on LIKE `abcd-1`?

Comment: @ h2ooooooo - I am not clear as to what you are suggesting

Comment: Why everyone using `LIKE` every time, why don't you try [FULLTEXT SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).    Its faster than `LIKE`.

Comment: @Pramod - I am using INODB engine

Comment: @Hacker read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html). In latest version innodb also  support fulltext search.

Comment: @Hacker do you have to stick with that database design or is there any way of changing it?

Comment: You need an index on `adjustment.code`. @Pramod, I don't see any word search going on here.

Comment: @MarcusAdams - Its already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic of your query without the `if()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM creditvouchers cv LEFT JOIN
     adjustment a
     ON a.`code` like concat(cv.creditvoucher, '%') and cv.creditvoucher <> '' or
        a.code = '';
```

MySQL is very bad about optimizing joins with `or` in the `on` clause.  However, the real challenge is this part:

```
select *
from creditvouchers cv left join
     adjustment a
     on a.code like concat(cv.creditvoucher, '%') and cv.creditvoucher <> ''
```

I would suggest that you think about your data structure.  I suspect that an intermediate table, `CreditvoucherCode` would help your system.  This would have one row for each credit voucher and code.

Another possibility is that if each `creditvoucher` has the same length, say 4, then you can add another field to `adjustment` that contains the `creditvoucher`.

Answer (score 0):

I also would suggest that you use an numeric id for your voucher and another table where you have the mappings between a voucher and your orders. in this mapping table you would only have ids to match against which is far faster than varchar comparison with LIKE.

If you would like to know what adjustments you have, you simply search for the voucher in your table and join it with the voucher_id in the mapping table.